# Should be a simple mod_rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

This rule does not seem to be functioning, however I cannot determine why, it looks fine to me:

```
RewriteRule ^shop_en/proddetail.php?prod=(.+)$ /shop/product/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Its like it does not get processed at all, I simply get my sites error message stating it cannot find 'proddetail.php'.

Which is weird too, because on a quick test I tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^shop_en/proddetail.php$ /shop/product [L,NC,R=301]
```

Which worked fine. So what is going on?

**Edit**: The product ID's that I am working with can contain letters, numbers and dashes.

In the simplest terms, with the most convenient definitions:

I want to route anyone trying access:

`www.domain.com/shop_en/proddetail.php?prod=333`

To the following URL:

`www.domain.com/shop/product/333`

**how can I do this?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^/?shop/product/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ shop_en/proddetail.php?prod=$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Your first answer worked.  Why doesnt it work the other way around??

Comment: What do you mean the other way around?

Comment: I want to go FROM proddetail.php?prod=333 **to** /shop/product/333

Comment: The first part of the rewrite rule is what you want it to look like and the second part is the original url.  Would you need the shop_en part of the url?

Comment: that isn't right, the first part is the URL given by the client, the second part is where it redirects to.

Comment: I've got loads of rewrites and they're all written like my answer and they work

Comment: Ditto! See: `RewriteRule ^contact.php$ /contact [L,NC,NE,R=301]` - This takes the given URL `contact.php` and redirects it to `/contact`.

Comment: Have a look here http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/. There is an example like RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ display.php?country=$1&state=$2&city=$3 [L]

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you're trying to match `QUERY_STRING` in `RewriteRule`. You will need a `RewriteCond` to match `QUERY_STRING`.

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+shop_en/proddetail\.php\?prod=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /shop/product/%1? [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^shop/product/([^/]+)$ /shop_en/proddetail\.php\?prod=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you - but it doesnt appear to be working - shouldnt the last line be the other way around?

Comment: Rules are correct and should work if used properly. When you comment something is not working you need to provide all the relevant details For which URL it didn't work? Are there more rules? What is location of this .htaccess file etc